Alternate product for Algar–Flynn–Oyamada reaction
For reference, this is the actual Algar-Flynn-Oyamada reaction:

I was wondering if an alternate product can be formed
I was told that the hydroxy group can be removed without the requirement of acidic medium (as in Hock rearrangement)
If it doesn't work (which it shouldn't) then does that mean ngp reaction is faster than migration?
Ngp?- I meant in the third step of this version of the mechanism (the actual Algar-Flynn-Oyamada reaction):


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Cuckoo Beats, welcome to ChemSE. In the first line of equations leading to the α-diketone, the likely product is the chromenone 1, formed by enolization of the diketone in basic medium. Take a look here.
In the second set of six structures, the first three have a four carbon chain linking the aromatic rings when there should be three. Consequently, the "arrow pushing" doesn't make sense. Your fourth structure, the enolate, were it to form would belie the fact that the epoxidation is quite efficient under the reaction conditions. In addition, acidic conditions are necessary for the rearrangement of cumene hydroperoxide (Hock rearrangement). The "arrow pushing" in the fourth structure is incorrect because it doesn't lead to an oxidation but rather effects elimination of phenoxide to form chromone. I doubt that the last step in this sequence would be possible under the reaction conditions.
The last set of reactions that invoke the intermediacy of an epoxide is a solid approach. If I may digress, I offer an experiment to test this hypothesis. Prepare enone 2 via an aldol condensation between benzaldehyde and 2-hydroxymethylacetophenone. Epoxidation of 2 leads 3, which in turn produces aldehyde 4 upon $\ce{MnO2}$ oxidation. Treatment of 4 with alkaline peroxide will convert the aldehyde group to the required phenoxide (Dakin rearrangement) to test the cyclization and subsequent oxidation to chromenone 1. If successful, it does not mean that it is THE mechanism but rather A mechanism.


Ok yeah it makes sense now, this is like m-CPBA epoxidation. Yeah it is highly unlikely for hock rearrangement in a basic medium. Had it been acidic it would have happened (would it?)
Btw can you please share the link you hyperlinked with "here". It isn't opening :')

The link is fixed. The epoxidation is similar to m-CPBA in that they both form epoxides. The double bond in this epoxidation is an electrophile whereas in the epoxidation of cyclohexene m-CPBA is the electrophile.

I just noticed that the third structure in the link's reaction sequence is missing the phenolic OH group.

and I also discovered now that I didn't understand the reaction from 4 to 5, could you please explain, sorry :')

This is a Dakin oxidation. The phenoxide is generated in situ. It opens the epoxide followed by a final oxidation as in the AFO reaction.

thanks i understood completely, I just didnt understand why you called me unkown? maybe i didnt get some humour or maybe you just wrote my username idk
my pen name i have kept as Cuckoo Beats, I will update that as my username ig

You are no longer Unknown, Cuckoo Beats. If my answer helped, you, you might consider accepting it.

thanks, yeah my bad :')
